# How to stop my app being hibernate from clean master android app

Tags: android, performance, android-service, android-permissions

I have developed an app which give job to our users. My target group uses clean master app very frequently which completely kills my app and its services.

Due to which they are not receiving notification.
I can not deliver them best job based on their locations(Since services are also shut down).

How can I make my app restart even when clean master shuts down it ??

Comment: why down-vote to this question ?? any reason ?? I am struggling to find answer of this question..

Answer (score 0):

**2 Ways Two to do it.**
     1. Do not come in hit list of cleaner (by gentle consumption resource of Operating system e.g Battery, Data, Processor )
     2. Take Device administration permission then user even can not uninstall our app ***( Highly Not recommended)*** 

Then their would not be any option of Force-stop or Uninstall from any other app or even by user.

```
public class DeviceAdminControl extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onEnabled(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onDisabled(context, intent);
 }
}
```

Define device_admin.xml in xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <uses-policies>
    <force-lock />
  </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Do the Entry in Manifest

```
     <receiver
        android:name=".DeviceAdminControl"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:label="test"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Now we have to ask for permission by user from the main activity

```
 private void askForPermission{
      try {
          DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)    getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminControl.class);

        if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
            // try to become active
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Click on Activate button to secure your application.");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOR_EDIT);
        } else {
            // Already is a device administrator, can do security operations now.
            mDPM.lockNow();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
      @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (REQUEST_FOR_EDIT == requestCode) {
        if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // done with activate to Device Admin
        } else {
            // cancle it.
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

After these steps, this will be result
   [image]

**If you want to uninstall after this** 
   Setting>>Security>> Device Administration>>Select Your App>> Remove     Permission - Now It will be available for uninstall.

Comment: Even if your app has admin rights, it can still be killed by the system cleaners that come built in on some devices.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at setting up your service as a foreground service, in that way your service will remain running, in the same way than any music player applications.

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory. A foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing" heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

You can take a look at the Android official documentation here : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

In your service you just have to call this method:

```
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

And to stop your service being in the foreground

```
stopForeground(true);
```